# Getting build errors after installing the Multilingual App Toolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multilingual

My boss wasn't sure that the Multilingual App Toolkit would work with our .NET MVC website but thought I should give it a shot anyway. It installed fine and I was able to add the spanish translation files but I'm getting some very vague build errors now.

"The filename or extension is too long." without any reference to what file

"Generation of satellite resource dll failed calling al.exe"

"Could not copy the file "obj\Debug x86\qps-ploc\Our.App.Namespace.resources.dll" because it was not found." Which I would assume is the satellite resource dll that failed to generate.

My googling didn't turn up anything helpful for this stuff. And hell, it might not work at all seeing as how our project isn't a Windows or Windows Phone app.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the Multilingual App Toolkit from `Programs and Features`, download the latest version, and re-install.
This fixes the build issues.

Encountered the same problem with a console application, and now it is working.